# Is Mercator projection an affine trasformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, map-projections

A practical example lead me to believe that a geographical projection, such as the [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), is an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

However, when I checked on Wikipedia:

> More generally, an affine transformation is an automorphism of an
> affine space (Euclidean spaces are specific affine spaces), that is, a
> function which maps an affine space onto itself while preserving both
> the dimension of any affine subspaces (meaning that it sends points to
> points, lines to lines, planes to planes, and so on) and the ratios of
> the lengths of parallel line segments. Consequently, **sets of parallel
> affine subspaces remain parallel after an affine transformation.**

This isn't true when it comes to Mercator: parallel lines on the surface on a Mercator map aren't paralell on the surface of a sphere.

However, in practical applications, affine transformations seem to be describe the mapping from a spherical surface to a plane and vice versa. Ie the documentation of the affine package within Python language, says:

> Georeferenced raster datasets use **affine transformations to map from
> image coordinates to world coordinates.** The affine.Affine.from_gdal()
> class method helps convert GDAL GeoTransform, sequences of 6 numbers
> in which the first and fourth are the x and y offsets and the second
> and sixth are the x and y pixel sizes.

Ie this description claims that an affine transformation maps from planar to spherical surface.

What am I getting wrong here? Are there more than one definition of the term *affine transformation* (one mathematical, and one used by geographers), or am I making a mistake somewhere else?

Comment: For those who are interested in an application of affine transformation in the geographical sense, I recommend this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017863/how-to-find-a-particular-coordinate-on-a-sentinel-image-using-projtransform

Answer (score 1):

The Mercator projection maps a portion of a sphere  in $\mathbb R^3$ to a plane which is an affine space of dimension $2$. Consequently, it can’t be an affine transformation in the sense of Wikipedia definition.

However Mercator projection transforms in an conformal way the spherical coordinates, which belongs to an affine space of dimension $2$ to a plane.

*We’re dealing with two coordinates systems of a sphere here.*

Comment: How is $f(u) = \tanh u$ an affine transformation of $u$?  Perhaps I'm not understanding what you intend.

Comment: @TedShifrin My mistake. I meant Mercator projection is conformal.

Comment: Yup. Now we agree.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your quote

> Georeferenced raster datasets use affine transformations to map from image coordinates to world coordinates

is from [this Affine package](https://github.com/sgillies/affine). But I don't see any reference to Mercator there, so where did you get that from?

The quoted passage talks about affine transformations between *image coordinates* (on the plane) and *world coordinates*. Yes. But those would be another set of coordinates on a plane (on a planar map).

If you have a rectangular map of some small area, your *image* coordinates could be, for example, the pixel positions, with $x$ ranging from $0$ to $600$ and $y$ ranging from $0$ to $200$. To convert those coordinates to something globally meaningful, for example into [EPSG:3857](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection) coordinates, you could use an affine transformation. After the affine transformation, you have new $x'$ and $y'$ coordinates that you could call "world coordinates" because they would be coordinates on your 2D world map.

So is not the *affine* that is your problem; it is still the mathematical *affine* and it is between two planar coordinate systems. It is the *world coordinates* that is your problem.

Now how to transform those "world coordinates" into 3D Cartesian coordinates on the sphere, or into degrees of longitude and latitude, that's *another* transform that would indeed not be affine (except locally approximately).

image coordinates $\overset{f}\to$ world coordinates, $f$ affine, both coordinates on a flat plane

world coordinates $\overset{g}\to$ (latitude,longitude), $g$ for example Mercator projection, not affine

Does this clarify?